# How does Spring security handle http basic authentication?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have exposed some webservices in a RESTful manner. In my first form user needs to login and login credentials is sent in Authorization header in the following manner:

```
Authorization :Basic adajajffjfksal
```

Now in my security-context.xml I have secured the URL in the following way:

```
<http pattern="/login" create-session="stateless">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_AUTHENTICATED" />
        <http-basic />
</http>
```

After successful login I have another form from which some paramaters will be passed to the server on behalf of the User. Will session be created? Do I have to pass user credentials in Authorization header again? Will this login request be sessionless due to  'create-session="stateless"'?

Comment: If a user will be accessing this service in his browser, then you should know, that most browsers always send the Authorization header once it is set. So the user will stay logged in until he closes his browser - the bigger problem is getting him to log out and not getting him to stay logged in. - I do realize you are asking about the session, I just wanted to let you know, because you will encounter it eventually.

Comment: @Imazgon Say I am not using browser and consuming the resful web service from mobile device what happens now?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I would guess that the browser still sends the Authorization headers with every request, so the user stays logged in (that's the default behavior of most browsers). It would be different if you would consume the service with another application - then you would have to set the header manually every time - unless of course a session is present.

Comment: @Imazgon Will session be present? Wiill 'create-session="stateless"' prevent the creation of session?

Answer (score 1):

This piece of security-context.xml has little sense if any

```
<http pattern="/login" create-session="stateless">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_AUTHENTICATED" />
        <http-basic />
</http>
```

It contains `pattern="/login"`, so the whole block is only considered by spring security for the sole url `/login`. In other words it is ignored for any other urls.

It contains `create-session="stateless"`, so it will not create any session.

The result is that if you explicitely call `/login` URL with proper basic authentication headers, you will be successfully authenticated and the session will immediately be closed. So you will not be authenticated for following requests.